# Error:Could not determine Java version so can't run project in android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I just use android studio in ubuntu. I installed studio and created a blank project and run. In Messages gradle sync shows : `Error:Could not determine Java version`. When I run project then menu Edit configurations appears after clicking it Run/Debug configurations appears. When I click `Default=> Android Application`, in Target Device I choose Emulator but Prefer Android Virtual Divice show Unknown AVD.
How can I solve that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems that Android Studio does not recognize OpenJDK, so I need to install the OracleJDK.

Then I choose the path to Oracle JDK and it worked!

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=80376